# How do i stop the crown from falling straight through the K

Tags: animation, mesh, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, clipping

I'm trying to make an animation where the crown falls onto a K and lands in the extended part of the K, The top right hand portion. I got a nicely meshed K made, And the crown is ready to fall but whenever I do it just falls straight downwards, clipping directly into the K and just continues to fall. I made Both Rigid bodies, the K being a Passive rigid body, and the crown being an active rigid body. I followed the guides of a person who gave me an instruction on a previous post I had created on a separate account because I can't find The account anymore, He told me to parent a hollowed out cylinder with the crown, that way the crown would fall straight downwards and land inside the k like its supposed to. However, even after doing that the crown just falls straight down, as if the geometry of the K itself doesn't have the strength to hold the crown up at all. I also tried to do the ctrl+a thing that a person suggested in the comments, but it didnt seem to do anything. I even did the whole set origin to geometry, even though the K is passive currently. Nothing changed and the crown just falls directly down, and bounces off the ground. As if the K wasnt even there in the first place. I was not able to recreate what Was shown to me in the previous post and it only resulted in the crown clipping through the K endlessly. They are all on the same section I believe their called, in the rigid body  simulation, So i don't know why it wouldn't work the way its supposed to

[image: K With edges shown]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd08l.png) [image: Crown With edges shown] [image: Full scene] [image: Point of contact] [image: Crown falling through]
[The link to the file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dxo943g231g012pp9gz9r/Crown-3.0.blend?rlkey=y0bwr7c7lwhujyfzqgzvdqrgx&dl=0)

Comment: From cleaned comment I understood you already discovered wrong parenting (Cylinder to Crown ... it has to be an opposite). To avoid falling Cylinder through K letter "Apply Scale" (Ctrl+A) to Cylinder object. To expand your sim chances add to Cylinder Solidify modifier and for letter K "Set Origin to Geometry" that is not the issue for Passive objects, but it is to keep this habits. @RobinBetts ... thanks for handling this situation.